# maven test hangs

Tags: java, maven, junit

I'm experiencing a weird problem running unit tests from maven. I have a set of unit tests that run perfectly if running one by one. However when I run those from maven (mvn test) it hangs (blocks forever).

It always hangs at the same point (same test class) in class A that is used by this test. I tried removing the log creation from `A.class` and the test started to run successfully. This is the line:

```
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(A.class);
```

Here's the thread dump:

```
"main" prio=6 tid=0x00446c00 nid=0x1278 runnable [0x00a2f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.waitFor(Native Method)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.CommandLineUtils.executeCommandLine(CommandLineUtils.java:173)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.CommandLineUtils.executeCommandLine(CommandLineUtils.java:114)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:231)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.runSuitesForkOnce(ForkStarter.java:125)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:109)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin.execute(SurefirePlugin.java:619)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
```

I don't have any idea where to go from here. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: The ThreadDump is from the maven-process. It shows, that a commandline-process is spawned.

Comment: Maven spawns tests in a child process- can you get a thread dump of this child process?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a dead lock on a resource?  Given the comment about another maven-process being spawned, that could be an indication of where to go.  You could try to put synchronize in your test somewhere (or on all the methods) to see if it goes away.  If it does, then it might be  dead lock.